# SQL Server question : manipulate column to a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this table with a lot of rows:

| ID | date 1 | date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001-09-09 | 1992-10-10 |
| 2 | 2008-07-07 | 2021-01-01 |

And I would like to write a query to get this kind of result:

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001-09-09 |
| 1 | 1992-10-10 |
| 2 | 2008-07-07 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 |

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute simplest way:

```
SELECT ID, [Date] = [date 1] FROM dbo.TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, [Date] = [date 2] FROM dbo.TableName
ORDER BY ID;
```

On larger tables, though, other solutions that don't scan twice (like `CROSS APPLY`) will fare better. Or `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT ID, [Date]
  FROM dbo.TableName
  UNPIVOT ([Date] FOR d IN ([Date 1],[Date 2])) AS p
  ORDER BY ID;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a8681ea9250ea8c82b9fb0a170c3056c)

Answer (score 2):

One option is using a `CROSS APPLY`

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ([date 1])
                     ,([date 2])
             )B(Date)
```